Does Raba Hold That Mishnayot do not Need to Present Information in an Ascending Order of Novelty?
Tosfot's Premise: Mishnayot present cases in order of novelty - לא זו אף זו (See Tosfot Meilah 2a, ששחטן בדרום,  " דסדר משנתינו כך הוא ששונה אותו שיש בו חידוש יותר "בסיפא )
My Premise: Rabbinic Meilah is a greater novelty than Biblical Meilah. This is due to the fact that on a biblical level this particular sacrifice is useless due to an egregious defect, but nonetheless the rabbis instituted Meilah.
Raba (Meilah 2b) seems to disagree with one of the premises.
The Mishna in Meila 2a lists several sets of cases of defective animals which still retain the possibility of Meilah. Prima facie, they all retain biblical Meilah potentiality. The Talmud 2a expressly explains that the set of cases involving a holy of holies animal wrongfully slaughtered/blood received in the south of the courtyard goes first in the Mishna because it is the least novel (the defect, relatively speaking, is not that bad, and so it retains biblical Meilah). The set of cases involving wrongfully slaughtering/sprinkling blood of an animal at night, however, goes next because it represents an even greater defect (thus a greater novelty - that these latter cases, notwithstanding their more egregious defect, still retain biblical Meilah).
The Talmud then introduces a game changer on 2b:
תְּנַן: קׇדְשֵׁי קָדָשִׁים שֶׁשְּׁחָטָן בַּדָּרוֹם – מוֹעֲלִין בָּהֶן. בִּשְׁלָמָא לְרַב יוֹסֵף נִיחָא, אֶלָּא לְרַבָּה קַשְׁיָא! מַאי מוֹעֲלִין בָּהֶן – מִדְּרַבָּנַן.
We learned in the mishna: With regard to offerings of the most sacred order that were disqualified before their blood was sprinkled on the altar, if one slaughtered them in the south of the Temple courtyard, he is liable for misusing them if he derives benefit from them. Granted, according to the opinion of Rav Yosef, this halakha works out well. But according to the opinion of Rabba, it is difficult: The Gemara explains: What is the meaning of the clause: One is liable for misusing them? This means that one is liable for misusing them by rabbinic law, but they are not subject to the halakhot of misuse by Torah law.
To recap - the first set of cases in the Mishna per Raba (in R. Shimon) - the set of slaughtering/receiving blood in the south - is rabbinical Meilah only. The rest of the cases in the opening Mishna (night etc.), however, are biblical. BUT this means, per Raba, that a set of cases involving rabbinic Meilah precedes cases in the Mishna that involve Biblical Meilah?!! Are we still ascending in order of novelty? Does Raba even care?

You can't turn occasional Tosfos into a rule until you prove it consistent with the Mishna. So your premise 1 seems wrong. I'm not proficient in Tosfos, but I remember Rashi proposing a rule "אין הבטה אלא מלמעלה למטה" and the scripture orders to put the bronze snake on a high pole and "וְהִבִּ֛יט אֶל־נְחַ֥שׁ הַנְּחֹ֖שֶׁת וָחָֽי".

We do have mishnayot taught following the principle זו ואין צריך לומר זו
